# Injecting class into the JNIEnv in android jni

Tags: java, android, c++, c, apktool

C++ code:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_afl_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    
    // env->DefineClass(...)
}
```

I'm calling the above function from Java side code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        stringFromJNI();  // call cpp function


    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

My question is about the `env->DefineClass(...)` in cpp code.
As you see the android VM passes `JNIEnv *env` to my native function, so by using `env` pointer i have access to all of my java classes and i can use them (i have access to all of my java side classes and i can create instance object and do everything). 
But how can access to a class which is in another apk and it is in another package name ?
I wanna decompile the target apk and copy that class and inject that class to my `env` using the `env->DefineClass` function but i don't know how can i complete this task.
Thanks for any reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible. Android [does not implement `DefineClass`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#unsupported-featuresbackwards-compatibility):

> All JNI 1.6 features are supported, with the following exception:
> DefineClass is not implemented. Android does not use Java bytecodes or class files, so passing in binary class data doesn't work.

Even if *that* worked, your app's user very probably does not have access rights to another applications .apk.

Comment: Let's see a bit easier. We have a `classes.dex` file which contains a lot of classes. The only thing i need is exactly add these classes to my `JNIEnv` (even not all classes actually i need to add just 1 class). I think there must be a way.

Comment: This is not possible with plain JNI. Perhaps you can get an answer on [reverseengineering.se]...

Comment: (https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29745/injecting-class-into-the-jnienv-in-android-jni) I wait for new answers there!